# Large POST transfer only for logged-in users?

Tags: php, apache, http, post

On my homepage, users that are "logged in" (via a PHP-session), should be allowed to upload very large files (via standard HTML5/PHP/XMLHttpRequest/POST-formular). Therefore, I set 'post_max_size' to 0 in order to remove any restriction on the file size.

However, I want to avoid that now *everybody* can send arbitrary large POST data to my server and block it. I want to *first* validate the login, and *then* accept a very large POST transfer to start.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Have not tested, but if you make a check and change current session config: `if ($user->isLogged()){ ini_set('post_max_size', $size) ; }`

Comment: Cool idea! Unfortunately, according to http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php, the function 'ini_set()' cannot override 'post_max_size'. However, it *can* be overridden within the .htaccess-file! This is already much better than setting it globally in php.ini, but still everybody can flood the server by sending POST-data to all the php-scripts within that directory. I try now a workaround with name-obfuscated temporary directories used for the upload...

Comment: What if you have a directory with increased `post_max_size`, but you let only logged in users in.

Comment: Yes, this would be easy with "Basic HTTP Authentication" (htpasswd), but how to do this with "PHP-Authentication"? That is, how to throw out non-logged-in users from that directory *before* they start sending large POST-data to any php-file in that directory? Indeed I managed this now by using Cookies and RewriteRule, but probably there is an easier way ?

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the comments of Jari, I implemented the following strategy, which works fine for me. Since I use HTTPS for the website and the file upload, this strategy is even save against network sniffing attacks.

My website is based on php, where logged-in users retrieve a php-session(-id).

`php.ini` has the default value of `post_max_size = 8M` back, so no large POST-transfers are accepted by my server in general.

When logging in, I set a temporary cookie `secret=XXXXXXXX` at the client, where the X's represent a random string that is also saved on server-side in `$_SESSION["secret"]`.

On the server-side, I create a web-accessible "user-directory" `tmp-YYYYYYYY` for each session, where the Y's are just another random string. In this directory, I put a symlink that points to my global `upload.php`-script that receives the file-uploads via POST from the upload-form (you could also just copy `upload.php` to the user-directory). Now, in order to allow that a POST-transfer to `tmp-YYYYYYYY/upload.php` may have unlimited size, I also create the file `tmp-YYYYYYYY/.htaccess` which contains the line `php_value post_max_size 0`. This enables to pass unlimited size POST-data to the linked upload-script. However, this is unsecure in the sense that *everybody* who knows/sniffes the URL `tmp-YYYYYYYY/upload.php` is able to send arbitrary large POST-data to this file, which may flood the server's tmp-directory. In order to avoid this, my full `.htaccess`-file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !secret=XXXXXXXX;?
RewriteRule ^ https://www.myserver.com/secreterror.php [L]
php_value post_max_size 0
```

That is, whenever the client that sends the large POST-data has no cookie with the secret value, then I re*direct* (since the target is an absolute url) him to some error-notification-script. This redirection does *not* forward POST-data, so no POST-data is stored on my server in this case. If the client has the correct secret cookie set, then the maximum allowed POST-data size is set to unlimited for the user-directory, thus for `upload.php`.

Final comments:

- you can also use `post_max_size 4G` in order to not allow 'really' arbitrary large data
- you can also overwrite other php-values here, all those that are labeled as `PHP_INI_PERDIR` in [this](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) list
- in order to be able to allow to override `post_max_size` in `.htaccess`, apache must not run php in CGI mode, but as an apache module. You can check for this by `phpinfo()` in the field "Server API". See [here](https://support.tigertech.net/php-value) and [here](http://www.opensource-excellence.com/blog/item/416-how-to-determine-php-is-running-as-php-cgi-or-apache-module?.html)
- the `mod_rewrite` apache module must be enabled, for example by `sudo a2enmod rewrite` plus restarting apache `service apache2 restart`
- probably your virtual host configuration must be be modified such that `.htaccess` is allowed to enable rewriting, for example by `AllowOverride All`
- without HTTPS, the cookie is transmitted unsecurely, so the method is then vulnerable to network sniffers, just like php-sessions via HTTP in general, too
- instead of creating a single directory for each session, containing its own `.htaccess`-file for a single secret key, one could alternatively use for all users the same upload-file (in its own single directory), and store/update all temporary secret keys in a data-base, and then use a modified `RewriteCond` that checks this data-base for the secret key that is passed in the cookie